# Update the keycloak account temporary password from our own website once super admin creates a user account

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, keycloak, keycloak-services, keycloak-rest-api

Here I'm using keycloak for the user management of my website. I want to send a password reset email once the keycloak super admin creates a user account. The email reset password link should route to my own website reset password page (Not to keycloak reset password page).

I'm done with up to here.

The issue is when sending the password reset request, expected following values...

```
session_code: xxxx
execution: UPDATE_PASSWORD
client_id: client-id
tab_id: xxxxxxxx
```

How can I get session_code and tab_id to create a reset password request from my own website?

I tried with decoding the key that comes with the email link. but couldn't find a way.